# Sorting an array of objects based on a property in an Angular controller using $filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I have an array of objects called `$scope.segments` like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "55d1167655745c8d3679cdb5",
    "job_id": "55d0a6feab0332116d74b253",
    "status": "available",
    "sequence": 1,
    "body_original": "Such a fork",
    "__v": 0,
    "body_translated": "Tal bifurcación"
  },
  {
    "_id": "55d1167655745c8d3679cdb4",
    "job_id": "55d0a6feab0332116d74b253",
    "status": "available",
    "sequence": 0,
    "body_original": "So this is it.",
    "__v": 0,
    "body_translated": "Así que esto es."
  }
]
```

I need to order this by array by sequence. So, I need the sequence 0 to appear first, the sequence 1 to appear next, and so on. In a view, I'm doing this and it works:

```
<ul ng-repeat="segment in segments | orderBy: 'sequence'">
    <li>{{ segment.sequence }}</li>
</u>
```

However, I need the orderBy filter to work in a controller. I'm doing this:

```
$scope.test = $filter('orderBy')($scope.segments, 'sequence');
```

Where, $scope.test should be my ordered array of objects based on the the sequence property. However, when I do console.log('$scope.test') an empty array (`[]`) shows. I imagine the $filter is not working in the controller.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: be sure that `$scope.segments` is not empty when you print it, because `ng-repeat` listens on `segments` change

Answer (score 7):

I guess you just didn't inject the `$filter` service in your controller properly, because this worked for me.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <ul ng-repeat="segment in segments | orderBy: 'sequence'">
    <li>{{segment.sequence}}</li>
  </ul>

  <script src="vendors/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    angular.module('app', [])

    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
      $scope.segments = [
      {
        "_id": "55d1167655745c8d3679cdb5",
        "job_id": "55d0a6feab0332116d74b253",
        "status": "available",
        "sequence": 1,
        "body_original": "Such a fork",
        "__v": 0,
        "body_translated": "Tal bifurcación"
      },
      {
        "_id": "55d1167655745c8d3679cdb4",
        "job_id": "55d0a6feab0332116d74b253",
        "status": "available",
        "sequence": 0,
        "body_original": "So this is it.",
        "__v": 0,
        "body_translated": "Así que esto es."
      }
    ];
      $scope.test = $filter('orderBy')($scope.segments, 'sequence');
      console.log($scope.test);
    }]);
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Sorry guys, the objects comes from a $resource call to an aPI. Doing in the view {{ segments | json }} prettyfies the object. However, doing console.log('$scope.segments'); shows that the object is a promise. How to sort inside this promise that cointains the objects?

Comment: Usually the promise will contain the model data somewhere inside of it. ex. `$scope.segments = injectedPromise.data[0];`

Answer (score 3):

You can always just sort the array (then you can even omit the `orderBy` in the view - although you lose some of the magic with the bindings if anything is added):

```
$scope.segments.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.sequence - b.sequence;
});
```

Comment: Tried this but not working, unfortunately. Here's what I have in `main.js`

    $scope.segments = SegmentsService.getSegments(jobId); // gets the segments from the API
   
    $scope.segments.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.sequence - b.sequence;
    });

    console.log($scope.segments);

In the view, I have: `<pre>{{ segments | json }}</pre>`

So, I get the segments from the API, and in the view I show them with segments | json. An after the sorting is done, the object sorted is printed in the console. Here's a screenshot: http://imgur.com/UUBDpXq

Comment: That API call is async - so the sorting is occurring before the array is populated.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by tymeJV, the API call is async, and so the question is missing data to help answer it.